# Azure intergration with service bus topic

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azureservicebus, adp

I am building an integration using API's from ADP. There is already an endpoint that I will be using - this is tied to a azure service bus. I have the name of the topic but I'm having trouble understanding the next artifacts that need to be created in Azure. I want the incoming messages to hit an EDW or just the data lake as data (it might be coming in as XML format, which I may need to convert to azure sql database):

- Should I create another subscription tied to the EDW that can pick up the messages from the service bus topic? (I have not attempted this before)
- Or Should I create a logic app to directly read the service bus or service bus topic? (I have not attempted this either)

I need to design a scalable solution - any insight would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: logic app, function, or just use sdk. Do you need any tutorial?

Comment: yes please as I'm a little unfamiliar with the service bus concepts and how to connect that to an azure integration package

Comment: Thank you !, Bowman Zhu  - can you expand on this answer or is there documentation to see how to linked the service bus topic to azure function then dump into data lake?

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: Hey  - I actually went a totally different route - let me know  if this is good way to go  -  so im actually working in JSON  and since the messages are going to the cosmos DB - I am just going to create a pipeline in ADF to read from there and copy into a azure sql database and then  flatten it out with data flow  so it can make a true table - let me know you thoughts... here is link - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/transform-complex-json-structures-from-cosmosdb-to-sql-db-with/ba-p/1221106

Answer (score 1):

> can you expand on this answer or is there documentation to see how to
> linked the service bus topic to azure function then dump into data
> lake?

I'm not sure what language you use, here is implemented in python.

You can use a service bus trigger to listen the messages come in of the service bus queue or topic. Then you can use data lake SDK to save the message:

Use azure function service bus trigger to listen the message:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):

    #put the logic of process the message here

    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queuename",
      "connection": "bowman1012_SERVICEBUS"
    }
  ]
}
```

And use code like below to append messages to data lake:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient 
connect_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=0730bowmanwindow;AccountKey=xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
datalake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
myfilesystem = "test"
myfolder     = "test"
myfile       = "FileName.txt"

file_system_client = datalake_service_client.get_file_system_client(myfilesystem)            
directory_client = file_system_client.create_directory(myfolder)         
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(myfolder)
print("11111")
try:
    file_client = directory_client.get_file_client(myfile)
    file_client.get_file_properties().size
    data = "Test2"   
    print("length of data is "+str(len(data)))
    print("This is a test123")
    filesize_previous = file_client.get_file_properties().size
    print("length of currentfile is "+str(filesize_previous))
    file_client.append_data(data, offset=filesize_previous, length=len(data))
    file_client.flush_data(filesize_previous+len(data))
except:
    file_client = directory_client.create_file(myfile)
    data = "Test2"   
    print("length of data is "+str(len(data)))
    print("This is a test")
    filesize_previous = 0
    print("length of currentfile is "+str(filesize_previous))
    file_client.append_data(data, offset=filesize_previous, length=len(data))
    file_client.flush_data(filesize_previous+len(data))
```

If you need to develop azure function on local, you need 'azure function core tools','language environment','VS Code and azure function extension'.

For more information, please have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python

And this is the API reference of data lake SDK(In this web page you can find all the methods of interacting with various services based on python and azure):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakeserviceclient?view=azure-python